# strcpy pass initialized null pointer c

Tags: c, strcpy

I'm trying out the following code:

```
int main()
{
   char *yo = "yo";
   char *whaddup = NULL;
   strcpy(whaddup,yo);
}
```

and I get a segfault. Complete C noob here - other places say I should initialize `whaddup` as an array. Why can't I pass in a pointer to null?

Comment: Same reason you can't do `char *whaddup = NULL; *whaddup = 'a';` for example. Which is also the same reason you can't do `int *whaddup = NULL; *whaddup = 4;`

Comment: @immibis whats the reason please?

Comment: A NULL pointer doesn't point to anything

Comment: @immibis but we can do `char *in = NULL; in = fgets(you.first_name, 100, stdin);` where `you` is some struct. Does this mean we can assign a pointer to the variable `in` to make it point somewhere else, but not a literal?

Comment: Well `in` doesn't contain NULL after you assign something that isn't NULL to it. If I do `int in = 5; in = 4;` then in contains 4 after this runs, and doesn't contain 5. `in = something;` is not the same as `*in = something;` - the latter doesn't modify `in`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just any [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) documentation will tell you that the destination string should be a `char` array large enough to hold the string and the `NUL` terminator.

So what you need is something like

```
char* yo = "yo";
char* whaddup = malloc(strlen(yo)+1);
strcpy(whaddup, yo);
```

Or alternatively you could use `strdup` function which does this for you, but it's not standard as it's POSIX only.

Comment: I only included the sizeof(char) to demonstrate the conceptual memory allocation, but yes @user2635088 a character is one byte so you don't need it. Safe to get in the habit of using it when you begin allocating int, double, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have to either declare `whaddup` as a character array or ideally allocate space for it with `malloc`.

```
int main()
{
   char *yo = "yo";
   char *whaddup = malloc(sizeof(char) * 8); // buffer for 8 characters
   strcpy(whaddup,yo);
}
```

By initializing `whaddup` to `NULL` you are not giving it any space in memory, so even copying one character into it will result in a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a pointer to null, but you can not copy string from pointer to null.

The function `char* strcpy(char* dest, const char* src)` is copy string from address `src` to address `dest`, your `dest` is `null`.