# Out of program of C language of pointer and Strcpy

Tags: c, pointers, output, strcpy

Consider the following C code snippet:

```
char *sentence = NULL;
strcpy(sentence, "Helloworld");
printf ("%s", sentence);
```

is the code segment correct or error? If correct what is the output?

a) Error

b) Helloworld

c) Null.Helloworld

d) None of the above

Comment: You have to allocate enough memory for `sentente`. Your code invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: It leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so *anything* could happen, including calling [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: Perhaps you should have compile this code to know the answer?

Comment: Picked up from some question paper?

Comment: What do you think will happen when you put a string into a NULL pointer? This is a suicide behavior that should be avoided in any circumstances

Comment: "*Perhaps you should have compile this code to know the answer?*" <- for **undefined behavior**, I don't think this is the best advice ;)

Comment: Normally whenever you get some simple task as homework you are tought the topic before. Which part of your course material is unclear?

Comment: @Felix Palmen too bad kernel memory segment is too far away and protected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strcpy pass initialized null pointer c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38065778/strcpy-pass-initialized-null-pointer-c)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

None and any. Dereferencing a *nullpointer* (and, copying data to it means it is dereferenced) is **undefined behavior**, there's nothing you can tell about the behavior of the program. A crash is of course very likely.

Comment: ..and equally unlikely. It can just behave as proper memory allocation would have been done. No guarantees, whatsoever.

Comment: With a nullpointer, it's much more likely to crash. Modern operating systems will catch that. But it's outside the scope of C anyways.

Comment: thanks for the help. I was also getting the same, undefined behavior as I executed this segment, but wasn't able to find the reason, which I got now.

Comment: @BDH I'd (really) like to see a machine where a program with undefined behavior endangers your life ;) Well, as a programmer.

Comment: @Felix Palmen I guess an overflow in rocket launcher program will be a suitable candidate:)